# why jest.mock return an mocked object with a default property?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I was trying to mock an object as below:

```
export default person = {
   firstName: "xxx",
   LastName: "xxx",
   getFullName: () => this.firstName + this.LastName
}

jest.mock('../person', () => ({
  getFullName: () => "John Smith"
}));
```

so I only want to mock the getFullName method, but when I ran jest, I found person is mocked as:

```
{
   default: { getFullName: () => "John Smith" }
   ...
}
```

how can I get rid of "default" property as I only want:

```
{
   getFullName: () => "John Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace mock with spyOn method.

`jest.spyOn(person, 'getFullName').mockImplementation(() => "John Smith");`